# Geth: Unable to mine test ether

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm trying to mine test either on a private testnet using geth on windows 7, but do not appear to actually be mining anything.  Geth seems to stall indefinitely after checking the DAG for epoch 0, while consuming 100% of my CPU. Ran it overnight in this state with no progress.

This is the command I'm using to start geth:

> geth --identity "Anon" --rpc --rpcport "8080" --rpccorsdomain "*"
>   --datadir "G:\EthTest" --port "30303" --nodiscover --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" 
>   --networkid 1999 console init genesis.json

The difficulty in my genesis block is "0x200"

I have tried allocating myself ether in the genesis block like this, and I still do not appear to have any test ether:

> "alloc": {
>       "0xmy_account": {
>           "balance": "10000000000000000000"
>       }

Thanks!

Comment: `console` should be the final geth command, not `init genesis.json`. You should also mention the path for your genesis file.

Comment: Check [this](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/faster-way-to-generate-dag) and [this](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6916/disable-automatic-pregeneration-of-dag) for problems related to DAG

Comment: genesis.json is in the same directory I'm launching geth from, but rearranging the args has worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rearranging the args and launching the console with a separate command has fixed this.  Mining success!

Here's the changed command:

> geth --datadir "G:\EthTest" --identity "Anon" --rpc --rpcport "8080"
> --rpccorsdomain "*" --port "30303" --nodiscover --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3" --networkid 1999 init genesis.json
>
> geth --datadir "G:\EthTest" --identity "Anon" --rpc --rpcport "8080" --
> rpccorsdomain "*" --port "30303" --nodiscover --rpcapi
> "db,eth,net,web3" --networkid 1999 console